# how to load the div contain after got all data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

i am trying hide and show my div element, but when i hide the top div, the below div show then ( but must be refresh ) it will not loaded after we refresh, 
and when i log out, i show back my homepage, but need to refresh also, how to handle this ??

```
if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
  $("#isLoggin").hide();
  $("#logout").show();
  $("#homepag").hide();
  $(".container-nav").css({ height: "50%" });
  $("#article").show();
} else {
  // $("#aframe").hide();
  $("#article").hide();
  $("#homepag").show();
  $("#logout").hide();
  $("#isLoggin").show();
}
```

my homepage like this

```
<div class="container-nav">
  <div id="homepag">

  </div>

  <div id="article">

  </div>
</div>
```

can i make loading loader when trigger to article and hide the hopepage?
i am on SPA

Comment: I did not understand, explain step by step

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. `When I hide the top div` - what is the top div? What is the below div? What ***should*** happen? `It will not loaded after we refresh` -  what does that mean? What do you mean by "refresh" - press F5? Why do you need to *refresh* - ***how*** do you refresh, and what happens if you don't? Please explain more carefully, with pictures if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you question is like a logic puzzle, lol. I finally got what you're asking!
The answer is yes, do this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
  $("#isLoggin").hide();
  $("#logout").show();
  $(".container-nav").css({ height: "50%" });
  $("#article").show();
  $("#article").siblings().hide();
} else {
  // $("#aframe").hide();
  $("#article").hide(); // hide this with CSS instead
  $("#homepag").show();
  $("#logout").hide(); // hide this with CSS instead
  $("#isLoggin").show();
}
```

Comment: Also, it would be way easier to manage if you did this: if (localStorage.getItem("token")) { $(".logged-out").hide(); }   and hide the ones that shouldn't show if you're logged in with CSS